# Proving that one can't tile a rectangle with irrational side ratio using squares

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to follow miniature 12 in [Thirty-three Miniatures: Mathematical
and Algorithmic Applications of
Linear Algebra](https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf) where Matousek proves that it isn't possible to tile a rectangle the ratio of whose side are irrational with a square. There are many statements in the proof that are beyond my level. I want to ask here in the hope that people can give me pointed hints and clarifications.

He starts with a rectangle of sides $1$ and $x$, where $x$ is an irrational number and assumes a tiling exists. The $n$ squares that tile it are $Q_i$ with side $s_i$ with $i$ going from $1$ to $n$. He then shows that this is impossible.

1. First, he considers the set of real numbers, $\Bbb R$ as a vector space over the field $\Bbb Q$ of rationals. I don't understand what this means.
2. Let $V \subseteq \Bbb R$ be the linear subspace generated by rational linear combinations of $x$ and the $s_i$'s. Does this mean $V$ contains numbers of the form $r_0 x+\sum_i r_i s_i$ where the $r_i$ are rational numbers?
3. Define a mapping, $f: V \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(x)=-1$. This is possible because $1$ and $x$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$. Not sure what this means. First, how do we know $1$ is even in $V$ given that $x$ is irrational and all the $s_i$'s might be as well?

There is a little more to the proof, but I'm hoping getting clarification on the three points above will give me a path towards understanding it.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) is a summary of basic vector space theory.  $1\in V$ since one side of the rectangle is $1$.  The squares that lie alongside the $1-$side must have sidelengths that sum to $1$.